# Why does "window = window.parent;" create an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, dom

I was traversing through a frame hierarchy, and tried the following to find the top frame:

```
var win = window;
while (win.parent) {
    //perform actions on win
    win = win.parent;
}
```

By now, I know that the correct looping condition must be:

```
while (win !== top) {
```

The existence check on `win.parent` seemingly creates an infinite loop. Is there any particular reason why it is like this? Why should `top` have a parent?

Comment: Have you tried to check what's `top.parent` ?

Comment: Perhaps that is how 'top' is flagged - maybe the top frame has itself as a parent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should also check if `window.parent == window​` is `false`. Otherwise you will end up with an infinite loop. If there is no parent, the parent property will reference to itself (infinite loop).

```
var win = window;
while (win.parent && win.parent != win) {
    //perform actions on win
    win = win.parent;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EZfHf/

I found this [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent):

> If a window does not have a parent, its parent property is a reference
>   to itself.

Answer (score 2):

`top`'s parent is itself.

```
top == top.parent //true
```